# onsen-ui gestures not working

Tags: onsen-ui, gestures, monaca

I need to implement a menu with the exact same looks as onsen sliding-menu,but that slides from top. I was thinking to use onsen gestures to be able to drag the menu, but the gestures sample provided in the onsen guide does not work. Am I missing something?

```
  <ons-gesture-detector>
    <div id="detect-area" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;background-color:blue;">
      Swipe Here
    </div>
  </ons-gesture-detector>

  <script>
    alert("in");
    $(document).on('swipeleft', '#detect-area', function() {
      alert("swipe");
    })
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it should work. Don't forget to add jquery first.

```html
<ons-gesture-detector style="height: 300px; margin: 50px 50px;">
    <div id="hoge" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: #f9f9f9; width: 100%; height: 300px; line-height: 300px; text-align: center; color: #999;">
        ...
    </div>
</ons-gesture-detector>
```

```js
<script>
    var eventName = 
      'drag dragleft dragright dragup dragdown hold release swipe swipeleft swiperight ' +
      'swipeup swipedown tap doubletap touch transform pinch pinchin pinchout rotate';

    $(document).on(eventName, '#hoge', function(event) {
      if (event.type !== 'release') {
        $(this).text(event.type);
      }
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: @user3526468 glad it helped! Please consider to upvote my answer. It will help future users, with the same problem, to find the solution easily.

Comment: I'd definitely do that, but I only have 14 reputation and upvote requires 15. Will upvote when/if I get there.